# Error "error TS18003: No inputs were found in config file" in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc

How can I fix this error? I'm running [Windows 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11).

When I try to `npm run build` on the cmd, I get this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmPSa.png)

#### File *package.json*

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17xSS.png)

#### File *tsconfig.json*

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es2016",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "rootDir": "XSHOPPER-BACKEND",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "outDir": "build",
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "strict": true,
  "skipLibCheck": true
},
```

Comment: If you can, please change the image of the error into a code block of text. Also, you seem not to have shown the full tsconfig.json file. The error is at line 102, but you only have a dozen or so lines shown.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73462450/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a tsconfig.json file is putting the `"include"` field under `"compilerOptions"`, but [`include` is a top-level field of the tsconfig.json schema](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include). It probably just needs to be moved to the right place.